# Cant open cooja simulator recently but worked fine before

Tags: iot, contiki, cooja

I am working on cooja simulator in contiki OS and it worked fine till now without any error and now its showing this error.
Used to open cooja simulator using terminal.
Also, upon analyzing the hard disk it still has 500 mb left and I am wondering does the memory gets used as I use cooja.
 
Help Required.
I am unable to add image, sorry about that.
Here is the error I am getting
user@instant-contiki:~/contiki-2.7/tools/cooja$ ant run
OpenJDK Client VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   /tmp/hsperfdata_user/2806
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

Buildfile: /home/user/contiki-2.7/tools/cooja/build.xml

init:

compile:

copy configs:

jar_cooja:
[jar] Building jar: /home/user/contiki-2.7/tools/cooja/dist/cooja.jar

BUILD FAILED
/home/user/contiki-2.7/tools/cooja/build.xml:226: Problem creating jar: No space left on device

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: 500 MB is very small number these days if talking about disk space. Some temporary files created during the build of cooja.jar may be larger than that.

Comment: So should I clean them? If yes, how can it be done?